# Oracle: grant to role if role exists

Tags: sql, oracle

How to execute

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON <ownschema>.<sometable> TO <somerole>;
```

but backing off gracefully if `somerole` does not exist. The user executing the statement is a standard user (think SCOTT) without any special privileges.

Version: Oracle Database 19 or later

Comment: Why is a "standard" user issuing this at all?   And if said standard user is competent to issue such a statement, they should be competent enough to recognize the error message and act accordingly.

Comment: @EdStevens.  Isn't it logical that the user himself would be the one who grants others access to his own objects?

Comment: What's "logical" is that objects are owned by the _application_ schema, not individual users. That is how _well designed_ systems are structured.   What's "logical" is that if someone has the ability to grant a privilege on an object, and doing so is part of their job, that they also - as part of their job - know how to deal with common error messages that result from that command, that they don't need to be insulated from it.

Comment: @EdStevens. In Oracle there's no distinction between the concept of a USER and the concept of a SCHEMA (a namespace) ... unlike in say MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc, where the concepts are separated. So, yes, the application has its own distinct schema, human users login as they themselves, etc. When referring to "the user", I meant the schema owner. Admittedly the lack of distinction between these two concept in Oracle trips me up sometimes.
And yes, I do think it is most logical for the object creator to be the one who also grants permission on such object.

Comment: Regardless of oracle's architecture, where "owner" and "schema" are virtually synonymous, you _did_ say "the user executing the statement is a standard user (think SCOTT) without any special privileges " . . .   In any event, we still come back to said user executing the query either should not be executing it (and so should receive the error message) or should be competent to deal with the error message.  Either way, no point in trying to "gracefully exit".

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't have made the SCOTT remark. It is a scripted continuous rollout (think GitOps) to approx 50 Oracle instances in a large enterprise. It cannot be predicted in advance if all of the 50 instances has `somerole` or not, but _if_ the role exists it should be granted to. There's no human involved who can take action based on an on-screen error message.

Comment: Ok, so as long as the error doesn't cause the script to abort, then 'no harm, no foul'.  Most installation/rollout procedures will produce a certain amount of 'ignorable errors'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can.

If you're running it at SQL level, then Oracle will raise an error if role doesn't exist.

If you want to check whether it exists, you'll need some kind of a PL/SQL procedure (which is not a problem), but - DBA should grant you `select` privilege on `dba_roles` so that you could check it. Then, if it exists, you'd grant that privilege; otherwise, return some kind of an information (dbms_output.put_line in my example is pretty much stupid; it wouldn't be visible out of SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD and similar), but you got the idea, I hope.

Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure p_grant_to_role (par_role in varchar2) is
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*) 
    into l_cnt 
    from dba_roles
    where role_name = par_role;
    
  if l_cnt > 0 then
     execute immediate 'grant select on emp to ' || par_role;
  else
     dbms_output.put_line('Role does not exist');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the tool, but you can do something like this (very crude as usually you should have better exception handling):

```
begin
execute immediate 'grant .....';
exception
when others then null;
end;
```